# Problem using variables in test actions in Firefox

Tags: firefox, automated-tests, e2e-testing, web-testing, testcafe

I am getting this error:

```
 1) Error on page "http://localhost:8080/en/index.html":

      import declarations may only appear at the top level of a module:
          No stack trace available
```

whenever I run my test on Firefox. My tests are written in Typescript and are testing my page locally. The tests have no problems in Safari and Chrome, only in Firefox does it complain about import declarations. I have tried to recreate the error in non-local sites but have not been able to.

```
import { Selector } from "testcafe"

const full = "http://localhost:8080/en/index.html"

fixture`This is my tests`
    .page`http://www.example.com/`;

test("URL", async t => {
    const logo = Selector(".Logo")
    await t
        .navigateTo(full)
        .expect(logo.textContent).contains("LogoName")
})
```

Hoping someone can shed some light on how to fix this!

Comment: I'm guessing that it is something to do with this issue: https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe-hammerhead/issues/1725

Answer (score 3):

Can you open the page in Firefox and check if you have error message in the JS console?
Testcafe will fail if there is any JS error.
You can use `--skip-js-errors` flag to ignore js errors (https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/using-testcafe/command-line-interface.html#-e---skip-js-errors) or ... fix that error on your page.